# BSOD DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL during install of nmap-7.70-setup.exe on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, nmap

Downloaded [nmap-7.70-setup.exe](https://nmap.org/download.html) and tried to install but got BSOD `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` as seen below on Windows 10. `What failed: jnprns.sys`.

[image]

Comment: The [download page for Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows) says, "Note: The version of Npcap included in our installers may not always be the latest version. If you experience problems or just want the latest and greatest version, download and install the latest Npcap release."

Comment: @bonsaiviking True but I think a lot of people, including myself, often go with the included version in the installer. Good thing to note though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key here was looking at `What failed: jnprns.sys`.

Looking at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\jnprns.sys` you could see it was signed by `Juniper Networks, Inc.`. With this information I could trace that `jnprns.sys` probably was used by a program called `Pulse Secure`.

[image]

Started by stopping the service and checked Task Manager that the process really had exited:

[image]

[image]

NMAP and specifically Npcap that caused the BSOD before could then be installed.

[image]

It was hard finding something related to this so I hope this post can help someone else.

Comment: Npcap 0.99-r2 is outdated. You can get the latest (with many bugfixes) on https://npcap.org/#download . However, I have encountered some crashes in jnprns.sys (Pulse Secure VPN) that were unrelated to Npcap, so this crash may be unrelated as well.

Comment: @bonsaiviking Happened when installing Npcap and when I disabled the service everything worked so in this case they are related I think. Nice addition with the link to the latest version!